# How to compare bytes of array in stream which i have write it before?

Tags: vb.net

I want to check if my edited stream have my bytes but the result is always failed I just can't find the wrong with my function

```
Public Function passbyte(ByVal filename As String, ByVal pass As String) 
                          As Boolean
    Dim passarray(0 to 2) As Byte
    Dim realarray(0 To 2) As Byte
    Dim result = False
    Dim pos As Integer

    pos = 0
    If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Using Stream As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
            Stream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            passarray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass)
            Stream.Write(passarray, 0, 3)
            Stream.Read(realarray, 0, 3)
            If realarray(0) = passarray(0) and realarray(1) = passarray(1) and realarray(2) = passarray(2) Then
                result = True
                MsgBox("Success")
            Else
                result = False
                MsgBox("Failed")
            End If

        stream.close()
        End Using
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make that much sense. Why are you writing to the stream and reading from the same stream? Besides just testing if the `pass` value matches the file, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks ! it's helpful, yes i need to create new stream to read,problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this without the loops?

```
If pass = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filename) Then
```